# Software questions: similarities and differences

Tags: discussion

There have been a few previous similar questions on Meta (like [this](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/786/should-we-be-answering-requests-for-recommendations) and [this](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/should-this-site-help-with-specific-writing-software-questions)).

Browsing through some old questions, I found [this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/which-sort-of-features-are-required-for-a-text-editor-in-order-to-improve-effici) question. It asks about the features that should be present to improve comfort and efficiency.

[This](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/whats-a-good-writing-software-for-android-phones-tablets) is about software recommendation asking which is a good writing software.

They have, to certain degree, similarities and differences to [this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10486/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-ipad-mini-friendly-pdf-file) question which is currently on hold. These questions ask for software recommendation and are to a certain degree subjective. There are other similar questions like [this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/suggest-any-good-text-editor-for-mac-for-writing-in-multiple-languages) and so on.

Now, the question on hold is also about software recommendation (specific to electronic publishing) . I believe it has a few similarities to other questions that have answers.

What are the points of differences based on which this particular one is on hold? Or do we go back and lock the older questions which are primarily asking for software recommendation?

Opinions and thoughts?

Comment: It looks (on a quick skim) like the one that's on hold is different from the others in one key respect: it's asking about tools for producing a particular kind of *output*, while the others ask about tools used *to write in the first place*.  We might handle these cases differently.

Comment: Thanks @MonicaCellio. That kind of clears it up.

Comment: Well, that only addresses the one question.  I haven't read all the linked questions yet, but I can easily imagine that we're not being consistent with this, and if that's the case we should talk about it.  Please feel free to edit your question as needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that older questions weren't necessarily subject to the same kind of scrutiny current ones are; the site hadn't yet defined itself. But I closed the ipad/pdf question, and although I stand by that, some clear policy to point at would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> [which features, writers like to have in their text editor and why?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/which-sort-of-features-are-required-for-a-text-editor-in-order-to-improve-effici)

That's the very definition of "opinion-based". Voted to close.

I already commented on the Android question in your first linked question, hence I don't repeat it here.

I wouldn't have put the iPad-mini question on hold. I my opinion it's about publishing and on-topic. But I have to say, that the suggested sites by Neil may serve the OP better. They have probably more users who already needed a way to make PDFs iPad-friendly.

Comment: The Ipad/PDF question - it seems more of a software recommendation than anything else. Superuser rejected the question outright on that basis. If we could rewrite it to be more of a publishing question, it would make more sense here. That said, I agree that this is an edge case. If a couple of people voted to reopen, I'd cast the final vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to note here on Meta (thanks for the opportunity) that there is a new Software Recommendations Site in Beta right now.  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

The general expectation is that a user comes in with a goal and a list of requirements and the community provides options, so the "What should I use to do X, Y and Z could be ported over there.

Also...Lauren, I created an opportunity for you to plug scrivener.  [Software for managing the writing of a book](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2274/259)